# Using AngularJS, how do I set $scope properties in the controller of the parent page

Tags: angularjs

Thanks for looking.

I have the following markup for a modal which shares the same angular controller as it's parent page:

```
  <!-- START Add Event Video -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="EventVideo.html">
        <div class="event-modal">
        <div class="modal-header"><h3>Event Video</h3></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please enter the URL of either a <strong>YouTube</strong> or <strong>Vimeo</strong> video.</p>
        <span ng-if="!Event.VideoUrlIsValid" style='color:#9f9f9f;'>This doesn't look like a valid YouTube or Vimeo Url.  Your video may not work.</span>
        <div class="row" ng-controller="EventCreateController">
             <div pr-form-input span="12" name="videoUrl" ng-model="Event.Item.VideoUrl" placeholder="YouTube or Vimeo URL" isRequired="false" no-asterisk></div>                                          
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="Event.UI.EventVideoModal.Close()">Done</button></div>
        </div>
    </script>
    <!-- END Add Event Video -->
```

And here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
 EventVideoModal: {
                Open: function () {
                    $scope.EventVideoModal = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'EventVideo.html',
                        controller: 'EventCreateController',
                        scope: $scope
                    });
                },
                Close: function () {
                    $scope.EventVideoModal.close();
                }
            }
```

Please note the `Event.Item.VideoUrl` model reference.

The modal allows a user to set the URL of a video, and the goal is to have that set `$scope.Event.Item.VideoUrl` in the controller and then close the modal.  The parent page and the modal both share the same controller, so I had hoped that this would work.

The modal behavior is fine (opens and closes as it should), but the `$scope.Event.Item.VideoUrl` property is not getting set.

Any advice is appreciated.

## Problem Solved!

Thanks to Bogdan Savluk, I realized that I had a scope inheritance problem.  So, removing both the explicit reference to the controller in the modal HTML as well as in the JavaScript constructor, resolved my problem:

```
 <!-- START Add Event Video -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="EventVideo.html">
            <div class="event-modal">
            <div class="modal-header"><h3>Event Video</h3></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please enter the URL of either a <strong>YouTube</strong> or <strong>Vimeo</strong> video.</p>
            <span ng-if="!Event.VideoUrlIsValid" style='color:#9f9f9f;'>This doesn't look like a valid YouTube or Vimeo Url.  Your video may not work.</span>
            <!-- <div class="row" ng-controller="EventCreateController"> <--REMOVE THIS! -->
<div class="row">
                 <div pr-form-input span="12" name="videoUrl" ng-model="Event.Item.VideoUrl" placeholder="YouTube or Vimeo URL" isRequired="false" no-asterisk></div>                                          
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="Event.UI.EventVideoModal.Close()">Done</button></div>
            </div>
        </script>
        <!-- END Add Event Video -->
```

And here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
 EventVideoModal: {
                Open: function () {
                    $scope.EventVideoModal = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'EventVideo.html',
                        //controller: 'EventCreateController', <--REMOVE THIS!!
                        scope: $scope
                    });
                },
                Close: function () {
                    $scope.EventVideoModal.close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing `scope` to `$modal.open()` than scope for modal would be created as child scope from passed `scope`... - so you will have access to all properties from it.

But in case when you are passing the same controller to it - that controller would be applied to new scope and will override all properties from parent.

So in general, as I see the only thing you need to do to achieve desired result is to remove controller from configuration passed to `$modal.open()` or replace it with something that is specific only for that modal.